# Why do we have that $ \sqrt{ 1 + \frac{- \log \log n}{\log n} + o(\tfrac{1}{\log n})} = 1 + \frac{- \log \log n}{2\log n} + o(\tfrac{1}{\log n}) $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, logarithms, taylor-expansion

I don't understand, why the following is true:
$$
\sqrt{ 1 + \frac{-  \log \log n}{\log n} + o\left(\tfrac{1}{\log n}\right)} = 1 + \frac{-  \log \log n}{2\log n} + o\left(\tfrac{1}{\log n}\right).
$$
I know that the $1/2$-factor on the RHS comes from the series expansion of the Binomial series. But I don't see why the little $o$-factor remains the same. Shouldn't the new $o$-factor on the RHS be
$$
o\left(\tfrac{\log \log n}{\log n}\right)  + o\left(\tfrac{1}{\log n}\right)
$$
?

This problem is taken from the book "Extremes and related properties of random sequences and processes" form Leadbetter, Lindgren, Rootzén. It seems like it is an error.

[image: Extremes]

Comment: @CarlMummert Please see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct one is
\begin{align}
\sqrt{ 1 + \frac{-\log \log n}{\log n} + o\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right)} &= 1 + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{-\log \log n}{\log n} + o\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right)\right)+o\left(\frac{-\log \log n}{\log n} + o\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right)\right)\\
&= 1 + \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{-\log \log n}{\log n} + o\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right)\right)+o\left(\frac{\log \log n}{\log n} \right)\\
&= 1 - \frac{\log \log n}{2\log n} + o\left(\frac{1}{\log n}\right)+o\left(\frac{\log \log n}{\log n} \right)\\
&= 1 - \frac{\log \log n}{2\log n} +o\left(\frac{\log \log n}{\log n} \right).\\
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, please see my updated question.

Comment: Yes, it is a mistake.

Comment: I will try to figure out if the proof in the book can still be saved.

Comment: Yes. You have 
$$
o\left(\frac{\log\log n}{\log n}\right)=o\left(\frac{1}{(\log n)^{3/2}}\right)=o(a_n^{-3/2}) \to 0
$$
and the proof still works as it is. Just replace the correct error term.

Comment: Is the reason for the first equality in your last comment, that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log \log n}{(\log n)^{1/2}} = 0$?

Comment: @user98187609 Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Note that by definition

$$o(\tfrac{\log \log n}{\log n})  + o(\tfrac{1}{\log n})=o(\tfrac{\log \log n}{\log n}) $$

indeed, with $\omega_i(n)\to 0$

$$o(\tfrac{1}{\log n})=\omega_1(n)\cdot\tfrac{1}{\log n}$$

$$o(\tfrac{\log \log n}{\log n})=\omega_2(n)\cdot\tfrac{\log \log n}{\log n}$$

then

$$o(\tfrac{\log \log n}{\log n})  + o(\tfrac{1}{\log n})=\omega_1(n)\cdot\tfrac{1}{\log n}+\omega_2(n)\cdot\tfrac{\log \log n}{\log n}=\omega_3(n)\tfrac{\log \log n}{\log n}$$

indeed

$$\omega_3(n)=\omega_1(n)\cdot\tfrac{1}{\log \log n}+\omega_2(n)\to 0$$

Note also that we can write correctly for the little-o term

$$o(\tfrac{\log \log n}{\log n})  + o(\tfrac{1}{\log n})$$

while the given little-o term

$$o(\tfrac{1}{\log n})$$

is uncorrect indeed let

$$o(\tfrac{\log \log n}{\log n})  + o(\tfrac{1}{\log n})=\omega_1(n)\cdot\tfrac{1}{\log n}+\omega_2(n)\cdot\tfrac{\log \log n}{\log n}=\omega_4(n)\tfrac{1}{\log n}$$

then

$$\omega_4(n)=\omega_1(n)+\omega_2(n)\cdot \log \log n$$

but we can't conlcude that

$$\omega_2(n)\cdot \log \log n \to 0$$